# Sparrow-Framework duplicate symbol error

Tags: xcode, cocoa, sparrow-framework

I am need of some assistance with sparrow framework(http://www.sparrow-framework.org/)/xcode 4/ and my project. I am Getting the following error:

```
Ld /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iDoubtIt.app/iDoubtIt normal i386
    cd /Users/alex/Dropbox/iDoubtIt/iDoubtIt-Sparrow
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Intermediates/iDoubtIt.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iDoubtIt.build/Objects-normal/i386/iDoubtIt.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -ObjC -all_load -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSparrow.a -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenAL -o /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iDoubtIt.app/iDoubtIt

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AIPlayer.hand in /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Intermediates/iDoubtIt.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iDoubtIt.build/Objects-normal/i386/Game.o and /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iDoubtIt-civshevejenwbzfqnllzztidnmzi/Build/Intermediates/iDoubtIt.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iDoubtIt.build/Objects-normal/i386/ApplicationDelegate.o for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take more care with tagging and formatting when posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have imported an implementation file (*.m file) in your "Game.m" or "ApplicationDelegate.m" file. You should not import implementation files. That causes your implementation file to get compiled two times. That causes duplicate symbol error.

To fix that problem you should fix your import line from `foo.m` to `foo.h`.